# Accessing/changing a button's values from another component when it may not exist

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if this is a very basic question, but I'm pretty new to React.

I have a component MiddleScreen which contains an array of buttons that will change throughout the app. Sometimes there may be 2 buttons, other times 6-8.

I have the front-end finished, but am trying to figure out both how to structure my app as well as how to actually interact with the buttons, especially when they may or may not exist.

I'm familiar with useContext and useState, so do I need to have a nested object containing all the details of each button, wrap it in a context provider, and set the state if the button exists?

I'll explain what I'm doing. I'm actually rebuilding an app I already made, that originally was made in vanilla js with 10,000 lines of code in a single script. Now I'm trying to rebuild it in React and clean up the code.

The UI looks like this.

[image]

And this is my folder structure (Looking for advice too on naming conventions I may be doing wrong or a better way to structure it?).

[image]

When pressing the start button, I need to adjust the text in TopScreen.js, which looks like this (I removed some irrelevant code).

```
const TopScreen = () => {
    const [topScreenText, setTopScreenText] = React.useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const text = 'This is some text that will change'
        setTopScreenText(text)
    }, [])

    return (
        <StyledTopScreen>
            <StyledTopScreenText>
                {topScreenText}
            </StyledTopScreenText>
        </StyledTopScreen>
    );
}

export default TopScreen;
```

I also need to be able to change the buttons. So I may need to change the buttonNumbers variable in MiddleScreen, or change the value of each button, etc. This is what MiddleScreen.js looks like.

```
const MiddleScreen = () => {
    function buttonPressed(button) {
        console.log(button)
    }

    const buttonNumbers = 7
    let middleButtonArray = []
    for (let buttonNumber = 1; buttonNumber <= buttonNumbers; buttonNumber++) {
        let letter = String.fromCharCode(96 + buttonNumber)
        let button = {
            key: letter,
            value: null
        }
        console.log('button ' + button.key + ' has value ' + button.value)
        middleButtonArray.push(button)
    }

    const middleButtons = middleButtonArray.map((middleButton) => {
        return (
            <StyledMiddleButton key={middleButton.key} onClick={() => buttonPressed(middleButton.value)}>{middleButton.key}</StyledMiddleButton>
        )
    })

    return (
        <StyledMiddleScreen>
            {middleButtons}
        </StyledMiddleScreen>
    );
}

export default MiddleScreen;
```

It's basically a trivia type app, where the user will be asked questions, and the buttons, number of buttons, and text will constantly change. The full app is fairly complex, and it took me 6 months to build it originally.

Now I'm trying to do it properly so I can add it to my portfolio, but I'm worried I'll get hundreds of hours into making this and realize I'm doing something wrong or inefficiently.

If someone could give me an idea of how I should be doing this I would really appreciate it.

I assume I need to be using state management like useContext, or should I be passing the props to each button directly? If so I would probably still need to use state management to know whether or not a button exists, right?

I've actually read a ton about React, done a few projects, but now that I'm building something that will be somewhat complex, I'm stuck endlessly trying to plan it and not really knowing how to do it in a way that doesn't immediately scream "This guy has no idea what he's doing" to someone who looks at the code.

Comment: How are `TopScreen` and `MiddleScreen` related, currently? Are they siblings within `App.js`?

Comment: This may be easier to design if you keep this one thing in mind at every step: React data only flows from higher nodes to lower nodes. Children components cannot talk to each other. If you need to share data between two components, you need to at least create state in their lowest common ancestor. This can be `useState`, Context, or a state library (which uses these two in some way.) If you want to share state between screen areas, you probably want to hoist the state management to `Device` or whatever component is rendering the screen sections.

Comment: @Nathan TopScreen is a div that displays text like questions during the trivia part. MiddleScreen is a div that has 2-8 buttons with the answer buttons for each question. I may also change it to display images at some point. App.js contains Device, which is a component that imports TopScreen, MiddleScreen, and BottomScreen.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate configuration of Button config for different screens/component like `const middleScreenBtnConfig =  [{ name:'btn1', value:"btn1" },{ name:'btn2', value:"btn2" }]` and use them accordingly.